# Responsive Design: how to modify css grid sizes at different screen resolutions?

Tags: jquery, css

Currently I am using something like this to modify grid sizes when a browser hits a certain width (break point), for example:

```
var width = jQuery(window).width();

if (width <= 480) {

    // Resize from grid_10 to grid_16 (Home, Featured, News)
    jQuery('.featured, .featured-page, .news-page, #footer-pagination').removeClass('grid_10').addClass('grid_16');
}
```

Is there a better approach to accomplish this? One of the issues I am experiencing is a slight "hickup" after the page initially loads as I can see the grid resizing from grid_10 to grid_16? Ideally I would like to eliminate this hickup.

Answer (score 1):

The App.net guys published an interesting solution a few days ago, where they define different grid unit classes for different breakpoints and switch between them using media queries: https://gist.github.com/3362608

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at css media queries here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

They are fast and work on mobile phones as well.

Comment: I'd also like to add, if you're looking for a HTML5 responsive framework to use you can take a look at the twitter bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

There are specific grid-frameworks for Responsive Design. I prefer Susy in use with Compass: http://susy.oddbird.net and http://compass-style.org